# Laravel Eloquent Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I use Eloquent in order to get price of my product in the database. Here is my code :

```
$this->record = DB::select('select * from get_price(?);', array($product_name));
$this->price = $this->record[0]->price;
```

I'm sure to get one price with this query. But when I execute my code I get the following error :

```
Undefined offset: 0 in line 2
```

**PHP don't find $this->record[0]**. So, I decided to use the following code :

```
$this->record = DB::select('select * from get_price(?);', array($product_name));
var_dump(isset($this->record[0]));
foreach ($this->record as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key);
    var_dump($value);
    var_dump($value->price);exit();
}
$this->price = $this->record[0]->price;
```

And I get :

```
// var_dump(isset($this->record[0]));
bool(true)

// var_dump($key);
int(0)

// var_dump($value);
class stdClass#2059 (2) {
  public $price =>
  string(2) "1"
  public $currency =>
  string(3) "USD"
}

// var_dump($value->price);exit();
string(2) "1"
```

I don't know why I can't access **$this->record[0]** but in a foreach of **$this->record** array I can access to the **0** index.

I'm using Laravel 4.2.

Comment: What is this `get_price()` do in your statement?

Comment: It's a Postgres function. It returns a price and currency of a product. As you can see in var_dump($value), in this exemple it returns 1 in price, and USD in currency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->record` is not an array but a **collection**.
Therefore you can't get an item using `$this->record[0]`.

In order to get an array you can call method `all()` of the  `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`.

This will work:

```
$r = $this->record->all();
dd($r[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this

```
$this->record = DB::select('select * from get_price(?);', array($product_name));
$this->price = collect($this->record)->first()->price;
```

It will only work if query fetches any record.

Comment: collect() is undefined. I didn't found any mention of collect() in Laravel or PHP documentation. Can you help me to import collect() function ?

Comment: Its there in Laravel but not in PHP. Check docs @ http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#creating-collections

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to say I use Laravel 4. I will add this information in my post.